# Custom Spring Data JPA query not returning specific columns

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called Topic and another entity called as Course. There is ManyToOne mapping from course entity to topic entity. Course entity has a field of Topic class annotated with `@ManyToOne`. I m trying to implement a custom CrudRepository method `public Course findCourseById(String id, String topicID)` which makes query to a specific course within a specific Topic with topicID and only returns certain columns. **(while querying for certain course I want to skip the certain columns nested inside topic object)**

##### Topic entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topic" , schema = "public")
public class Topic implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id ;
    private String name ;
    private String description ;

    public Topic() {
    }

    public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

##### **Course entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course" , schema = "public")
public class Course implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id ;
    private String description ;
    private String name ;
    @ManyToOne
    private Topic topic ;

    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(String id, String description, String name, String topicId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.name = name;
        this.topic = new Topic(topicId, "", "") ;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Topic getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(Topic topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }
}
```

I want to run this native query in such manner that it doesn't returns a field for topic.description. 
  

##### My custom query :

```
@Query(value = "Select course.id, course.description, course.name, topic.id as topic_id, " +
            "topic.name as topic_name " +
            "from public.course " +
            "inner join public.topic " +
            "ON course.topic_id = topic.id " +
            "Where topic_id = :topicId and course.id = :id " , nativeQuery = true)
    public Optional<Course> findCourseById (@Param("id") String id , @Param("topicId") String topicId) ;
```

The output it returns in pgAdmin query tool is as expected (not having any topic.description field) and shared below :

[image]

##### getCourse() method inside CourseService class

So far everything is working fine but there is problem at the service layer. 
Here is getCourse() method from CourseService class which is for the purpose of returning a single specific course present inside a specific topic.

```
@Cacheable(value = "course" , key = "#id + #topicId" , unless = "#request == null")
    public Course getCourse (String id, String topicId ){
        return courseRepository.findCourseById(id, topicId).orElse(null) ;
    }
```

The problem I have encountered is that it returns every possible column that can be mapped with JPA entity, even though the custom query returns data without topic's description column (as shown in my query above). 
As shown in the image below, in the nested object being returned when GET API request is made to route: *`localhost:8080/topics/top01/courses/course-05`* , there is a topic description field being returned and **I don't want the description field inside topic field  to be returned.** 
[image]

Since I m beginner to Spring Data JPA as well as Spring I have two doubts :

1. How is correctly mapped topic's description getting returned as JSON
   even when my custom query for this method isn't returning a
   `topic.description` column.
2. Secondly, If I want to make sure that the JSON being returned from
   the controller doesn't consists description field inside topic field
   then how can I achieve that and whether it be done  **without using DTO
   concept**  as I haven't touched that yet ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get custom object you need to use Spring Data JPA Projections.

First create an interface like

```
public interface CourseObj{
    String getId();
String getDescription();
String getName();
String getTopic_id();
String getTopic_name();
}
```

Then write your repository method like

```
@Query(value = "Select course.id, course.description, course.name, topic.id as topic_id, " +
            "topic.name as topic_name " +
            "from public.course " +
            "inner join public.topic " +
            "ON course.topic_id = topic.id " +
            "Where topic_id = :topicId and course.id = :id " , nativeQuery = true)
    public CourseObj findCourseById (@Param("id") String id , @Param("topicId") String topicId) ;
```

And try your service method like

```
@Cacheable(value = "course" , key = "#id + #topicId" , unless = "#request == null")
    public CourseObj  getCourse (String id, String topicId ){
        return courseRepository.findCourseById(id, topicId).orElse(null) ;
    }
```

You can find documentation and example here [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)

Comment: 1. Firstly, regarding your projection approach's code, I think we will need to define two separate interfaces, one for `TopicObj` and other as `CourseObj` (which you did). Reason for this being I want a nested JSON to be retuned which I believe can't be achieved only with the help of `CourseObj` interface projection.

Comment: 2. Secondly, the projection approach seems to be a bit hard-coded approach where i have to manually define all expected fields to be returned by a query. If in a scenario where the type of fields being returned varies time to time then i will have to update the projections manually. Isn't there any other option available which is elegant as well as less hard-coded ?